# Share a class variable in multiple instances of another class

Tags: python, class, global-variables

I have defined 2 Python classes, `A` and `B`. In class `A`, a list `a_list` is defined, which is quite bulky. Class `A` defines a large number of instances of class `B`. Each of those instances uses the same value of `a_list`. I want to prevent using global variables. The alternative is that I pass `a_list` as a parameter at each instantiation of `B`. I am afraid that this will use a lot of memory (`n` times the size of `a_list`). How can I define `a_list` in the instance of `A` and share its values in all instances of `B`?

```
g_list = [...., ....] #a bulky list 

class A():
    def __init__(self):
 
        global g_list
        b1 = B(p1)
        b2 = B(p2)
        ...
        bn = B(pn)


class B():
    def __init__(self, p):
        global g_list    
        ....
```

```
class A():
    def __init__(self):
        self.a_list = [...., ....] #a bulky list  
        
        b1 = B(self.a_list)
        b2 = B(self.a_list)
        ...
        bn = B(self.a_list)


class B():
    def __init__(self, a_list)
        ....
```

Comment: Can you make `a_list` a _class attribute_ instead of an _instance attribute_?

Comment: Passing a list as a parameter doesn't make a copy of it, it's just a reference. So you're not multiplying the amount of memory.

Comment: If you aren't duplicating the list, then every object has a reference to the same list; use `id` to confirm this if you're still not sure. Also, you don't just have a global or an instance attribute as options; you can also make it a class attribute.

Comment: What is `global g_list` used for? You never reference the list in either method.

Comment: I think I give it a try to just pass it as a parameter and have a look at memory usage. I don't understand the remark of Random Davis to use id.  Can you please explain?

Comment: Since every instance of `A` has its own `a_list`, you have to pass it as a parameter to `B`. Otherwise `B` wouldn't know which of the potentially many `a_list` objects (one per `A` object) it was referencing. In CPython, the reference is a pointer, typically 8 bytes. It will be stored on the `B` instance obect dict, so you would also have the overhead of the variable name and space in the dict key / value store. But that's just the cost of doing business in python.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with using a global variable for sharing a value among classes as long as it's meant to be read-only after its initialization. Plenty of modules in the standard library use global variables to share constant values. Also keep in mind that "global" variables in Python aren't truly global at all and are actually limited to the namespace of their defining modules so you don't have to worry about namespace pollution. Lastly, you don't have to use the `global` statement for read-only access to a global variable.

Answer (score 0):

I decided to pass the list as a parameter at creation time of the instances (so in the **init** routine.

I notice that an operation on the list in any of the instances ripples through in all other instances as it should.

Note that in my application the list is certainly not read-only.

Thanks for your replies.